# how to run a program with gdb which is invoked from a shell script, which in turn invoked from c++ via boost::process

Tags: c++, linux, shell, boost, gdb

I want to debug a c program with gdb which is invoked by shell script. In this shell script , there are lot of things done and many environment variables are set.

This shell script is invoked by boost::process::launch from a c++ program.

I can change c++ program, shell script, and the c program itself, but can't change the architecture of this flow.

Is there any way , so that i can use gdb to debug the program.

If there is no solution, is there a way to dump all environment settings before launching shell script, so that i can launch same script with these settings to debug it later. I will prefer a portable and long term solution.

Answer (score 2):

Two easy options:

1. Attach gdb after the program has started with `gdb -p <pid of process>` if it doesn't matter to stop it at a specific point.
2. Insert a `raise(SIGSTOP);` in the C program where you want it to stop. Once the process is stopped, attach gdb as in `1`, set any breakpoints you need and then send the process a `SIGCONT` signal (`kill -CONT <pid of process>`) to cause it to continue.

Comment: It is not portable solution, here i need some sort of no manual intervention and no code change at run time

Comment: Since you explicitly tagged the question "linux" I didn't think portability mattered.